# 802.11 in NS2.35

Tags: wifi, ns2

How can I run/simulate different 802.11 standards in single simulation?
Example: 802.11b and 802.11g run/simulate in single simulation.

Did I need to make any special configuration?

Answer (score -1):

Google, ns2 802.11b and 802.11g https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+802.11b+and+802.11g

Example http://network-simulator-ns-2.7690.n7.nabble.com/802-11g-b-implementation-in-NS2-td26003.html

```
set opt(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# channel type
set opt(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model
set opt(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type
set opt(mac)            Mac/802_11                 ;# MAC type
set opt(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue    ;# interface queue type
set opt(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type
set opt(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model
set opt(ifqlen)         50                         ;# max packet in ifq
set opt(adhocRouting)   DSDV                       ;# routing protocol
...

Mac/802_11 set SlotTime_          0.000020        ;# 20us
Mac/802_11 set SIFS_              0.000010        ;# 10us
Mac/802_11 set PreambleLength_    144             ;# 144 bit
Mac/802_11 set PLCPHeaderLength_  48              ;# 48 bits
Mac/802_11 set PLCPDataRate_      1.0e6           ;# 1Mbps
Mac/802_11 set dataRate_          11.0e6          ;# 11Mbps
Mac/802_11 set basicRate_         1.0e6           ;# 1Mbps
Mac/802_11 set RTSThreshold_      3000            ;# Use RTS/CTS for packets larger 3000 bytes
```

There are examples using more than one MAC type in one simulation : NIST-MOB

```
    # Topology scenario:
    #
    #                                   bstation802(3.0.0)->)
    #                                   /
    #                                  /      
    # router0(1.0.0)---router1(2.0.0)-----------bstation80216(4.0.0)          +------------------------------------+
    #                                  \                                  + iface1:802.11(3.0.1)|              |
    #                                   \                                     +---------------------+ MutiFaceNode |
    #                                   rnc(0.0.0)                            + iface0:UMTS(0.0.2)  |  (5.0.0)     |
    #                                      |                                  +---------------------+              |
    #                                 bstationUMTS(0.0.1)->)              + iface2:80216(4.0.0) |              |    
    #                                     +---------------------|          |
    #                                     + iface:LTE(0.0.3)    |          |    
    #                                             +---------------------+--------------+    
    # 1 Multiface node.
.    
.
.   
        # 802.11    
      Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1 set cost80211_   [lindex $argv 3]
      Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1 set energy80211_ [lindex $argv 4]

    #802.16
      Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1 set cost80216_   [lindex $argv 5] 
      Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1 set energy80216_ [lindex $argv 6]
      Agent/MIHUser/IFMNGMT/MIPV6/Handover/Handover1 set PER80216_ [lindex $argv 7]
```

INFO http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/nist-mob/